# Linked Server Security

Tags: sql-server

I have created a linked server from a SQL 2008 R2 instance to an Oracle instance, and it works properly.  I used the Be made using this security context button and entered a user and password from the Oracle instance.  Can anyone who can sign onto the SQL instance use the linked server?  I think they can, so can I limit who can query against the linked server?

Comment: There's a [similar question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43640/linked-server-available-to-users-without-permissions) on dba.stackexchange.  Check out Aaron Bertrand's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the first option: For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:

- Not be made

And you must Add a new login mapping so that Your local user say SA will remote to scott tiger.

This way, only SA will be able to use the link to Oracle.